# Como faço para acessar o iddoFeed e pegar todos os dados independente do usuário logado

Tags: firebase, react-native

[image]

```
firebase.database().ref('feeds').once('value').then((snapshot) => {            
        let feeds = []
        snapshot.forEach((childItem) => {
            feeds.push({
                key: childItem.key,
                id: childItem.val().id,
                id_user: childItem.val().id_user,
                url: childItem.val().url,
                date_posted: childItem.val().date_posted,
                name: childItem.val().name,
                avatar:childItem.val().avatar,
                like_count: childItem.val().like_count,
                is_liked: childItem.val().is_liked,
                //comments: childItem.comments
            })
        })
```

A busca que estou fazendo está retornando o id_user

Comment: Wagner [edite a sua pergunta e coloque essas informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375098/edit) lá

Answer (score -1):

ES6

```
firebase.database().ref('feeds').once('value').then(snapshot =>
    snapshot.map(s => console.log(s.id_user))
)
```

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso acessar o nó iddoFeed e buscar todos os dados do feed independente do usuário.